# -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; css scale pixelates in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, impress.js

I'm using impress js for my presentation.

http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/

In the overview mode of the slides I see pixelated view of the slide scaled down. Please see the below link in Chrome

http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/overview

[image]

In Firefox it looks properly.

[image]

Comment: I can't see the problem. Maybe non-Retina display is required?

Comment: I'm using Non-Retina Display. I've updated the question with screenshot of how it looks in firefox. @Pavlo